# How to add data at the end of a file

Tags: c

I would like to open a file and add data at the end of the file which the user has input and stored in a variable **amt**.

But my code is not working..

```
{
 fp=fopen("TRECIEPT.TXT","a+");
 while((temp=getc(fp))!=EOF);
 fprintf(fp,"\n");
 fprintf(fp,"%llu",&amt);
}
```

Comment: use fseek and seekend.

Comment: remove the `&` from the `amt` unless you really want the address of the variable. I also think you don't need to do the while thing as `"a+"` should position the writing at the file end.

Answer (score 4):

1) The following loop is unnecessary:

```
while((temp=getc(fp))!=EOF);
```

The `"a+"` already takes care of seeking to the end of the file.

2) The `&` in following is likely wrong:

```
fprintf(fp,"%llu",&amt);
```

3) Don't forget to close the file when you're done with it.